# RegEx failing for strings with less than 3 characters

Tags: regex

I am using a RegEx to test if a string is valid. The string must start and end with a number ([0-9]), but can contain comma's within.

I came up with this example, but it fails for strings less than 3 characters (for example `1` or `15` are as valid as `1,8`). Presumably this is because I am specifically testing for a first and last character, but I don't know any other way of doing this.

How can I change this RegEx to match my requirements. Thanks.

```
^[0-9]+[0-9\,]+[0-9]$
```

Comment: `^(?!,)[0-9,]*[0-9]$`

Comment: Are you using Javascript RegEx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9])?$
```

the `,[0-9]` part will be optional

visualized:

[image]

if you want allow for multiple comma-number groups... then replace the `?` with `*`.

if you want to allow groups of numbers after the comma (which didn't seem to be the case in your example), then you should put `+` after that number group as well.

if both of the above mentioned are desired, your final regex could look like this:

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$
```

[image]

Comment: Fails on 192312,9888. Might be good to get the exact requirements from OP, but so far its only starting and ending with a number with commas between.

Comment: Thanks, but it fails on `1,2,3`

Comment: @DavidGard, that is not true if you take in to account the note about replacing `?` with `*`. I didn't see that as a use-case when I initially read your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*$
```

should work.

Always have one or more digits at the start, optionally followed by any number of comma-separated other groups of one or more digits.

If you allow commas next to each other, then the second + should be a *, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the regex

```
\d(,?\d)*
```

Should satisfy for 1 or more digits that can be separated by only one comma. Note, 1,,2 fails